# Cannot populate JavaScript / jQuery /jsGrid using AJAX or other service on SharePoint 2013 with data from Azure SQL server

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, sharepoint, azure-sql-database

Simply put, *How can I communicate between javascript/jQuery and a SharePoint 2013 Azure SQL server back end?*

---

#### Details:

I created an MS Access Web App in Access 2016 on my company's Office 365 SharePoint Online site. When you create an Access Web App, an Azure SQL server is created on the back end and the data tables for the Access Web App are stored here.  I am successfully able to connect to my SQL data tables using SQL Server Management Studio.  However, I need to find a JavaScript or jQuery code that would allow me to pull this data and populate a read/write grid on my SharePoint site.  I've found many tutorials and codes to connect to a SQL database using PHP, but I don't believe those will work with SharePoint, as SharePoint is in ASP.NET or .NET and thus not compatible, right?

Are there any sort of SharePoint compatible datatables/jQueryGrid, etc. scripts that I could use to connect to my Azure SQL data?  I assume I need to use AJAX or something similar but cannot get anything to work.

Some additional connection information:

- Below is a string that is used in PowerApps or PowerBI to connect to
  the data - and it does work.  Is there something similar that can be included in a JavaScript code?

Server=tcp:MYSERVER.database.windows....,1433;Database=MYDATABASE;User ID=MYUSER;Password=MYPASSWORD;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;

I have created a DSN and have used ODBC and SQL Server 11 driver to connect in Excel.

Other items to consider:

- This is a free Azure SQL database (well, technically it's paid for by
  our Office 365 subscription), and not a standard Azure subscription
  account - therefore I cannot login to the Azure Management Portal to
  access this database.
- I am the Site Collection Administrator for this SharePoint site, but
  our corporate IT locks us out of SharePoint Central Administration,
  so I cannot use PowerShell or anything like that.  I also cannot use
  a SharePoint Developer site or Visual Studio or anything like that to
  compile anything.  I just need a script that will allow me to connect
  with my connection information.

A few more helpful background info links:

- Here's [a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16253250/connect-to-sql-azure-containing-backend-for-ms-access-web-app/) detailing more about connecting to these Azure SQL servers.
- [SharePoint 2013 - Accessing List data through web service from Sharepoint site, getting error 404](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19429763/sharepoint-2013-accessing-list-data-through-web-service-from-sharepoint-site)
- [How to Successfully Deploy a Lightswitch 2013 HTML App to Azure with a Linked SQL Server database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19872328/how-to-successfully-deploy-a-lightswitch-2013-html-app-to-azure-with-a-linked-sq)
- http://honeyvig.blogspot.com/2012/01/windows-azure-sql-azure-database.html

*Thank you all **very much** for any help you are able to provide!!*

Comment: I dont know anything about sharepoint itself. That said, I use a normal sql database and have a PHP application that sits between that database and my client side jQuery. When the client wants data, it calls to the php application which accesses the sql server, gets the data, formats it if needed, then returns it as JSON to my client code. Being a .net environment, you may have to use some other language to write that "middle man" portion, but you will need that to access the actual datastore.

Comment: What I mean is, you cant just connect your clientside code to your datastore. You need to write an application or RESTful service that bridges communication between the two. *unless sharepoint somehow has this functionality built in*